# undefined method `build_profile' for #<User:0x000000035b9ae8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out the problem with my code. I'm trying to add a profile to my user. For this I get my user ID and attach this to my profile in a DB. However after submitting the form it gives the following error: NoMethodError in ProfilesController#create

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  # GET to /users/:user_id/profile/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # POST to /users/:user_id/profile
    def create
      # Ensure that we have the user who is filling out form
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      # Create profile linked to this specific user
      @profile = @user.build_profile( profile_params )
      if @profile.save
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render action: :new
      end
    end
    private
      def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :contact_email, :banking)
      end
end
```

Comment: Show us your relations please.

Comment: You need to have the relations setup, update with modal pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models need to be some thing like this... I assume you are missing a `has_many` or `belongs_to` in the user modal.

```
class User
  has_many :profile
  # or belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  # or has_many :users
end
```

Give your modals if it doesn't work, we can fix it up.

Comment: That was the problem, fixed it by adding the has_many relation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@profile = @user.build_profile( profile_params )
```

by

```
@profile.user_id = current_user.id
```

for `user_id` it depend how you named your user id foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You may do

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  if @profile.save
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end

private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :contact_email, :banking, :user_id) 
  end
```

Or

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :contact_email, :banking).merge!(user: current_user) 
end
```

Regarding the error "NoMethodError in ProfilesController#create" it may happen because it is not declared in the `routes.rb` or it does a HTTP Get instead of a Post.

in the routes.rb file,

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources